# \cvskill with 6 circles instead of 5?

Tags: cv, altacv

I'm doing my cv and in the languages part i would like to have 6 levels to fill instead of 5; does anyone know a package that does this or how to modify \cvskill in order to have 6 levels (6 circles)?

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}

\geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.2cm}

\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{EagleGreen}{HTML}{104F55}
\definecolor{Myrtle}{HTML}{32746D}
\definecolor{CambridgeBlue}{HTML}{9EC5AB}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{heading}{EagleGreen}
\colorlet{headingrule}{CambridgeBlue}
\colorlet{subheading}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{accent}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}


% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

%% Use (and optionally edit if necessary) this .tex if you
%% want to use an author-year reference style like APA(6)
%% for your publication list
\input{pubs-authoryear}

%% Use (and optionally edit if necessary) this .tex if you
%% want an originally numerical reference style like IEEE
%% for your publication list
% \input{pubs-num}

%% sample.bib contains your publications
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
```

then i have the
begin{document}

(...)

```
\cvsection{Languages}

\cvskill{Portuguese (Native)}{5}
\divider

\cvskill{English (IELTS)}{5}
\divider

\cvskill{Spanish}{3}
\divider
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The tags on your question are a bit confusing, you have added both `moderncv` and `altacv` but those are two different document classes for CVs. So which one do you actually use (from mentioning `\cvskill` I guess it is `altacv`)? You can remove the other tag. For the question itself: it would make the question easier to answer if you provide a small complete document that produces a cv. Of course that can be anonymized, the actual details are not important - but seeing the code that you already have helps in determining what needs to be changed.

Comment: Hey @Marijn thank you for the clarification! yes, it is the altacv! I've removed the other tag, I'll add your suggestion now to the question with everything on the document before the "begin document" and with the part of the cvskill! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\cvskill` command is defined using a for loop from 1 to 5. You can change this to a for loop from 1 to 6.

To do this you can copy the original definition of this command from the class file (from line 312 in `altacv.cls`), put the definition in your own document, and change the number 5 to 6. However, because you want to overwrite the original definition, you need to use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`. You can put the redefinition anywhere in the preamble, for example just above `\begin{document}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,ragged2e,withhyper]{altacv}

\geometry{left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,columnsep=1.2cm}

\usepackage{paracol}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

% Change the font if you want to, depending on whether
% you're using pdflatex or xelatex/lualatex
\ifxetexorluatex
  % If using xelatex or lualatex:
  \setmainfont{Roboto Slab}
  \setsansfont{Lato}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\else
  % If using pdflatex:
  \usepackage[rm]{roboto}
  \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
  % \usepackage{sourcesanspro}
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fi

% Change the colours if you want to
\definecolor{SlateGrey}{HTML}{2E2E2E}
\definecolor{LightGrey}{HTML}{666666}
\definecolor{EagleGreen}{HTML}{104F55}
\definecolor{Myrtle}{HTML}{32746D}
\definecolor{CambridgeBlue}{HTML}{9EC5AB}
\colorlet{name}{black}
\colorlet{tagline}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{heading}{EagleGreen}
\colorlet{headingrule}{CambridgeBlue}
\colorlet{subheading}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{accent}{Myrtle}
\colorlet{emphasis}{SlateGrey}
\colorlet{body}{LightGrey}

% Change some fonts, if necessary
\renewcommand{\namefont}{\Huge\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\personalinfofont}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\cvsectionfont}{\LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cvsubsectionfont}{\large\bfseries}


% Change the bullets for itemize and rating marker
% for \cvskill if you want to
\renewcommand{\itemmarker}{{\small\textbullet}}
\renewcommand{\ratingmarker}{\faCircle}

\renewcommand{\cvskill}[2]{%
  \textcolor{emphasis}{\textbf{#1}}\hfill
  \BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={#2}}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,6}{%
    \ifdimequal{\x pt - #2 pt}{0.5pt}%
    {\clipbox*{0pt -0.25ex {.5\width} {\totalheight}}{\color{accent}\ratingmarker}%
     \clipbox*{{.5\width} -0.25ex {\width} {\totalheight}}{\color{body!30}\ratingmarker}}
    {\ifdimgreater{\x bp}{#2 bp}{\color{body!30}}{\color{accent}}\ratingmarker}%
  }\EndAccSupp{}\par%
}

\begin{document}
\name{Person Name}
\tagline{Guten Tag}
\personalinfo{on need to know basis}
\makecvheader
\columnratio{0.6}

% Start a 2-column paracol. Both the left and right columns will automatically
% break across pages if things get too long.
\begin{paracol}{2}
\cvsection{Languages}

\cvskill{Portuguese (Native)}{6}
\divider

\cvskill{English (IELTS)}{5}
\divider

\cvskill{Spanish}{2}
\divider
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked!!!

Comment: This solution changes the number of arguments for ``\cvskill`` to 2. When I try to implement this solution with only one argument (changing ``[2]`` to ``[1]``) I get an error: ``Illegal parameter number in definition of \cvskill. }``. Can you help me get this to work with just one parameter?

Comment: @And the two arguments (which the original class also has) are for the name of the skill and the level (i.e., how many of the bullets are colored). If you want just one argument, which one do you want, the name or the bullets? If it is just the name then you can more easily just put `\textbf{some name}`, which is basically what `\cvskill` does for the name. If it is just the bullets (which would be hard to interpret I think, what do just the bullets mean?) then you can remove the first line from the macro (where `#1` is used) and replace all the occurrences of `#2` by `#1`.